# How to display php variable values in html <li>

Tags: php, html

I have got multiple php variables that I want to display in html <ul list. The variables being displayed but not how I want it to be. It seems like one <li is inside of <ul correctly but, the other one is outside of <ul in it's own block and it's own <li even when I am displaying all of the variables inside of single <ul. Also the styling is only being applied to only the first <li element and not to the others.

Here is my html code

```
<div>
    <ul class="product-info-list">
        <li> <?php echo $dimensions; ?> </li>
        <li> <?php echo $materials; ?> </li>
        <p> <?php echo $description; ?> </p>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The source code from page source is

```
<div class="product-info-details">
<div>
    <ul class="product-info-list">
        <li>  18" x 10" x 6".</li>
     </ul></li>
        <li> Burlap,Nylon,Polyester </li>
        <p> <p>With the Fusion Backpack strapped on, every trek is an adventure - even a bus ride to work </p>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the output

[image]

The html structure that is getting created after doing what I am doing is,

[image]

Comment: In the page source (not the DOM inspector), what is the original HTML sent to the client for this `<div>`?

Comment: Please check the $dimensions variable, it might contain some HTML code, that's why it is breaking the syntax. Please share values of both the variables.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. We've no idea what the values of those variables are.

Comment: try `<?= htmlentities($dimensions); ?>` quotes or `<`, `>` in the string is breaking the html

Comment: The HTML structure in the Browser console is always tidied up and smartened so that can not always be reliable. You need to use the browser and "**View Source Code**" of the page and then copy/paste into your question here what that source code actually says.

Comment: @David, The original html sent to the client from page source is 

`</div></div>
   <div class="product-info-details">
   <div>
      <ul class="product-info-list">
        <li>  18" x 10" x 6".</li>
      </ul> </li>
        <li> Burlap,Nylon,Polyester </li>
        <p> <p>With the Fusion Backpack strapped on, every trek is an adventure - 
        even a bus ride to work 
     </p>
    </ul>
</div>`

Comment: @ShehrozAltaf, the Values of both variables are $dimensions = 18" x 10" x 6". and $materials = Burlap,Nylon,Polyester

Comment: @Quentin, Thank you, I will be careful from now on.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, Thank you, It works but, it also adds </li> </ul> at the end of the output on frontend

Comment: @LosMos: Then it appears that the values you're outputting contain HTML code, which makes the overall structure invalid.  Did you want to strip out that HTML before outputting it?  Encode it to be readable?  Change the structure to accommodate it?  Something else?

Comment: _"the Values of both variables are $dimensions = 18" x 10" x 6". and $materials = Burlap,Nylon,Polyester"_ - and the `With the Fusion Backpack ...` text comes out of thin air then? No, that makes no sense. Your variables contain more than you think they do. Use `var_dump`, and verify what that has to say about their length. You can also apply `htmlspecialchars` before you make the debug output, then < and > would get _displayed_ instead of interpreted as HTML.

Comment: @CBroe, ur concern is correct. It is my fault I should have provided the full code. The `With the Fusion Backpack`, is another variable called $description. That I added later on. I have edited my question.

Comment: @David, U were right, It did contain html tags. After wrapping my string inside of strip_tags(), it worked. Thank you.

Comment: `p` elements can't be children of `ul` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The page element cant be where you have it.   The `<p>` can not be between the `</li>` and  `</ul>`.  I can not find a suitable authoritative reference right now, but I have made the same mistake myself.

So I have shifted it inside the `<li>..</li>`

Try this.

```html
<div>
    <ul class="product-info-list">
        <li> <?php echo $dimensions; ?> </li>
        <li> <?php echo $materials; ?> 
        <p> <?php echo $description; ?> </p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Or maybe you intended this.  I have changed the `<p>` to a list element

```html
<div>
    <ul class="product-info-list">
        <li> <?php echo $dimensions; ?> </li>
        <li> <?php echo $materials; ?> </li>
        <li> <?php echo $description; ?> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn fromit. What did you change, and why?